# how to render a dynamic html which has some form controls

Tags: javascript, angular

html coming from back-end having tags with input form controls.
here is my code.

```
<form id="myform" [formGroup]="form"  (submit)="saveItem()">
 <div  [innerHtml]='htmlRender' ></div>
 <div>{{form?.value|json}}</div>
 <button type="submit" form="myform">SAVE</button>
 </form>
```

```js
form: FormGroup;



  fieldsHtml = {
    'Brand': {
      html: `<select class="form-control" id="Brand" formControlName="Brand">
   <option value="company1">Company1</option>
   <option value="company2">Company2</option>
   <option value="company3">Company3</option>
   <option value="company4">Company4</option>
 </select>`, field: {
        type: 'dropdown',
        name: 'Brand',
        label: 'Brand',
        value: 'company2',
        required: true,
        options: [
          { key: 'company1', label: 'Company1' },
          { key: 'company2', label: 'Company2' },
          { key: 'company3', label: 'Company3' },
          { key: 'company4', label: 'Company4' }
        ]
      }
    }, 'ContactNumber': {
      html: `<input  attr.type="text" class="form-control"  id="ContactNumber" name="ContactNumber" formControlName="ContactNumber">
`, field: {
        type: 'text',
        name: 'ContactNumber',
        label: 'Contact Number',
        value: '8747737343',
        required: true
      }
    },
    'ContactTel1': {
      html: `<input  attr.type="text" class="form-control"  id="ContactTel1" name="ContactTel1" formControlName="ContactTel1">
`, field: {
        type: 'text',
        name: 'ContactTel1',
        label: 'Contact Tel1',
        value: '',
        required: true
      }
    },
    'ContactTel2': {
      html: `<input attr.type="text" class="form-control"  id="ContactTel2" name="field.name" formControlName="ContactTel2">
`, field: {
        type: 'text',
        name: 'ContactTel2',
        label: 'Contact Tel2',
        value: '',
        required: true
      }
    },
    'DateEntry': {
      html: `<input attr.type="date" class="form-control"  id="DzteEntry" name="DzteEntry" formControlName="DzteEntry">
`, field: {
        type: 'date',
        name: 'DzteEntry',
        label: 'Date Entry',
        value: '2020-02-15',
        required: true
      }
    },
    'Datenotify': {
      html: `<input attr.type="date" class="form-control"  id="Datenotify" name="Datenotify" formControlName="Datenotify">
`, field: {
        type: 'date',
        name: 'Datenotify',
        label: 'Date Notify',
        value: '2020-02-15',
        required: true
      }
    },
    'DescriptionIncident': {
      html: `<input attr.type="text" class="form-control"  id="DescriptionIncident" name="DescriptionIncident" formControlName="DescriptionIncident">
`, field: {
        type: 'text',
        name: 'DescriptionIncident',
        label: 'Description Incident',
        value: '',
        required: true
      }
    },
    'FullName': {
      html: `<input  attr.type="text" class="form-control"  id="FullName" name="FullName" formControlName="FullName">
`, field: {
        type: 'text',
        name: 'FullName',
        label: 'Full Name',
        value: '',
        required: true
      }
    },
    'InjurdTimeHr': {
      html: `<select class="form-control" id="InjurdTimeHr" formControlName="InjurdTimeHr">
<option value="01">01</option>
<option value="02">02</option>
<option value="03">03</option>
<option value="04">04</option>
<option value="05">05</option>
<option value="06">06</option>
<option value="07">07</option>
<option value="08">08</option>
<option value="09">09</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
</select>`, field: {
        type: 'dropdown',
        name: 'InjurdTimeHr',
        label: 'InjurdTimeHr',
        value: '02',
        required: true,
        options: [
          { key: '01', label: '01' },
          { key: '02', label: '02' },
          { key: '03', label: '03' },
          { key: '04', label: '04' },
          { key: '05', label: '05' },
          { key: '06', label: '06' },
          { key: '07', label: '07' },
          { key: '08', label: '08' },
          { key: '09', label: '09' },
          { key: '10', label: '10' },
          { key: '11', label: '11' },
          { key: '12', label: '12' }
        ]
      }
    },
    'InjurdTimeMnt': {
      html: `<select class="form-control" id="InjurdTimeMnt" formControlName="InjurdTimeMnt">
      <option value="01">01</option>
      <option value="02">02</option>
      <option value="03">03</option>
      <option value="04">04</option>
      <option value="05">05</option>
      <option value="06">06</option>
      <option value="07">07</option>
      <option value="08">08</option>
      <option value="09">09</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
      <option value="11">11</option>
      <option value="12">12</option>
      </select>`, field: {
        type: 'dropdown',
        name: 'InjurdTimeMnt',
        label: 'InjurdTimeMnt',
        value: '25',
        required: true,
        options: [
          { key: '01', label: '01' },
          { key: '02', label: '02' },
          { key: '03', label: '03' },
          { key: '04', label: '04' },
          { key: '05', label: '05' },
          { key: '06', label: '06' },
          { key: '07', label: '07' },
          { key: '08', label: '08' },
          { key: '09', label: '09' },
          { key: '10', label: '10' },
          { key: '11', label: '11' },
          { key: '12', label: '12' },
          { key: '13', label: '13' },
          { key: '14', label: '14' },
          { key: '15', label: '15' },
          { key: '16', label: '16' },
          { key: '17', label: '17' },
          { key: '18', label: '18' },
          { key: '19', label: '19' },
          { key: '20', label: '20' },
          { key: '21', label: '21' },
          { key: '22', label: '22' },
          { key: '23', label: '23' },
          { key: '24', label: '24' },
          { key: '25', label: '25' },
          { key: '26', label: '26' },
          { key: '27', label: '27' },
          { key: '28', label: '28' },
          { key: '29', label: '29' },
          { key: '30', label: '30' },
          { key: '31', label: '31' },
          { key: '32', label: '32' },
          { key: '33', label: '33' },
          { key: '34', label: '34' },
          { key: '35', label: '35' },
          { key: '36', label: '36' },
          { key: '37', label: '37' },
          { key: '38', label: '38' },
          { key: '39', label: '39' },
          { key: '40', label: '40' },
          { key: '41', label: '41' },
          { key: '42', label: '42' },
          { key: '43', label: '43' },
          { key: '44', label: '44' },
          { key: '45', label: '45' },
          { key: '46', label: '46' },
          { key: '47', label: '47' },
          { key: '48', label: '48' },
          { key: '49', label: '49' },
          { key: '50', label: '50' },
          { key: '51', label: '51' },
          { key: '52', label: '52' },
          { key: '53', label: '53' },
          { key: '54', label: '54' },
          { key: '55', label: '55' },
          { key: '56', label: '56' },
          { key: '57', label: '57' },
          { key: '58', label: '58' },
          { key: '59', label: '59' },
          { key: '00', label: '00' }
        ]
      }
    },
    'ManagerName': {
      html: `<select class="form-control" id="ManagerName" formControlName="ManagerName">
      <option value="ram">ram</option>
      <option value="a">a</option>
      <option value="bv">bv</option>
      
      </select>`, field: {
        type: 'dropdown',
        name: 'ManagerName',
        label: 'Manager Name',
        value: 'jack',
        required: true,
        options: [
          { key: 'ram', label: 'Ram' },
          { key: 'shyam', label: 'Shyam' },
          { key: 'jack', label: 'jack' }
        ]
      }
    },
    'Name1': {
      html: `<input  attr.type="text" class="form-control"  id="Name1" name="Name1" formControlName="Name1">
`, field: {
        type: 'text',
        name: 'Name1',
        label: 'Name1',
        value: '',
        required: true
      }
    },
    'Name2': {
      html: `<input  attr.type="text" class="form-control"  id="Name2" name="Name2" formControlName="Name2">
`, field: {
        type: 'text',
        name: 'Name2',
        label: 'Name2',
        value: '',
        required: true
      }
    },
    'NotifyManager': {
      html: `<div class="form-check">
        name: 'NotifyManager',
<input formControlName="NotifyManager" class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="y" >
<label class="form-check-label">
  YES
</label>
<label class="form-check-label">
  NO
</label>
</div>`, field: {
        type: 'radio',
        name: 'NotifyManager',
        label: 'Notify Manager',
        value: 'n',
        required: true,
        options: [{ key: 'y', label: 'Yes' }, { key: 'n', label: 'No' }]
      }
    },
    'OtherDetail': {
      html: `<input  attr.type="text" class="form-control"  id="OtherDetail" name="OtherDetail" formControlName="OtherDetail">
`, field: {
        type: 'text',
        name: 'OtherDetail',
        label: 'Other Detail',
        value: '',
        required: true
      }
    },
    'PartofBody': {
      html: `<input  attr.type="text" class="form-control"  id="PartofBody" name="PartofBody" formControlName="PartofBody">
`, field: {
        type: 'text',
        name: 'PartofBody',
        label: 'Part of Body',
        value: '',
        required: true
      }
    },
    'PositionTitle': {
      html: `<input  attr.type="text" class="form-control"  id="PositionTitle" name="PositionTitle" formControlName="PositionTitle">
`, field: {
        type: 'text',
        name: 'PositionTitle',
        label: 'Position Title',
        value: '',
        required: true
      }
    },
    'ReturntoWork': {
      html: `<div class="form-check">
<input formControlName="ReturntoWork" class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="y" >
<label class="form-check-label">
YES
</label>
<label class="form-check-label">
NO
</label>
</div>`, field: {
        type: 'radio',
        name: 'ReturntoWork',
        label: 'Return to Work',
        value: 'n',
        required: true,
        options: [{ key: 'y', label: 'Yes' }, { key: 'n', label: 'No' }]
      }
    },
    'TimeAP': {
      html: `<select class="form-control" id="TimeAP" formControlName="TimeAP">
<option value="am">AM</option>
<option value="pm">PM</option>
</select>`, field: {
        type: 'dropdown',
        name: 'TimeAP',
        label: 'Time AP',
        value: 'am',
        required: true,
        options: [{ key: 'am', label: 'AM' }, { key: 'pm', label: 'PM' }]
      }
    },
//     'Treatment': {
//       html: `<div [formGroup]="Treatment" >
// <div class="form-check form-check">
// <label class="form-check-label">
//    <input formControlName="treatment1" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1" />
//    Treatment1</label>
//    <label class="form-check-label">
//    <input formControlName="treatment2" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox2" value="option2" />
//    Treatment2</label>
//    <label class="form-check-label">
//    <input formControlName="treatment3" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox3" value="option3" />
//    Treatment3</label>
//    <label class="form-check-label">
//    <input formControlName="treatment4" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox4" value="option4" />
//    Treatment4</label>
//    <label class="form-check-label">
//    <input formControlName="treatment5" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox5" value="option5" />
//    Treatment5</label>
// </div>
// </div>`, field: {
//         type: 'checkbox',
//         name: 'Treatment',
//         label: 'Treatment',
//         required: true,
//         options: [
//           { key: 'treatment1', label: 'Treatment1' },
//           { key: 'treatment2', label: 'Treatment2' },
//           { key: 'treatment3', label: 'Treatment3' },
//           { key: 'treatment4', label: 'Treatment4' },
//           { key: 'treatment5', label: 'Treatment5' }
//         ]
//       }
//     },
    'WhereIncident': {
      html: `<input  attr.type="text" class="form-control"  id="WhereIncident" name="WhereIncident" formControlName="WhereIncident">
`, field: {
        type: 'text',
        name: 'WhereIncident',
        label: 'Where Incident',
        value: '',
        required: true
      }
    },
    'Witnesses': {
      html: `<div class="form-check">
<input formControlName="Witnesses" class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="n" >
<label class="form-check-label">
  YES
</label>
<label class="form-check-label">
  NO
</label>
</div>`, field: {
        type: 'radio',
        name: 'Witnesses',
        label: 'Witnesses',
        value: 'n',
        required: true,
        options: [{ key: 'y', label: 'Yes' }, { key: 'n', label: 'No' }]
      }
    }

  }


  constructor(@Inject(DomSanitizer) private sanitizer: DomSanitizer,private fb:FormBuilder) {
    let arr = [];
    let htmldata = `<table class="CSSTableGenerator" style="width: 974px; height: 1342px;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 959.219px;" colspan="4">
                <h2>Register of Injuries, Incident &amp; Hazards</h2><strong style="text-align: justify;"> The purpose
                    of this form is to register a TTC workplace injury, incident, hazard or near<br />miss. This form
                    should be completed as soon as the injury, incident or near miss has<br />occured, or as soon as a
                    hazard is identified. </strong>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 248.141px;">Full Name</td>
            <td style="width: 348.172px;">
  
  <span id="FullName" class="fields" style="background-color: #f1c40f;">&lt;&lt;
                    FullName &gt;&gt;</span>
  
  </td>
            <td style="width: 157.359px;">Contact Number</td>
            <td style="width: 161.281px;">
  <span id="ContactNumber" class="fields"
                    style="background-color: #f1c40f;">&lt;&lt; ContactNumber &gt;&gt;</span>
  </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 248.938px;">Select Brand</td>
            <td style="width: 348.969px;">
  <span id="Brand" class="fields" style="background-color: #f1c40f;">&lt;&lt;
                    Brand &gt;&gt;</span>
  </td>
            <td style="width: 157.578px;">Position Title</td>
            <td style="width: 161.5px;">
  <span id="PositionTitle" class="fields"
                    style="background-color: #f1c40f;">&lt;&lt; PositionTitle &gt;&gt;</span>
  </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 249.172px;">Manager's name</td>
            <td style="white-space: nowrap; width: 696.094px;" colspan="4">
  <span id="ManagerName" class="fields"
                    style="background-color: #f1c40f;">&lt;&lt; ManagerName &gt;&gt;</span>
  
  </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 249.344px;">Have you notified your manager? Y/N</td>
            <td style="width: 696.016px;" colspan="3">
  <span id="NotifyManager" class="fields"
                    style="background-color: #f1c40f;">&lt;&lt; notifyManager &gt;&gt;</span>
  </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 959.219px;" colspan="4">
                <h2>Particulars of the Injury, Incident or Hazard</h2>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 249.344px;">Date of Injury</td>
            <td style="width: 349.172px;">
  <span id="DateEntry" class="fields"
                    style="background-color: #f1c40f;">&lt;&lt; DateEntry &gt;&gt;</span>
  </td>
            <td style="width: 157.594px;">Time</td>
            <td style="width: 161.656px;">
  <span id="InjurdTimeHr" class="fields"
                    style="background-color: #f1c40f;">&lt;&lt; InjurdTimeHr &gt;&gt;</span>
  :
  <span id="InjurdTimeMnt"
                    class="fields" style="background-color: #f1c40f;">&lt;&lt; InjurdTimeMnt &gt;&gt;</span>
  /
  <span id="TimeAP" class="fields" style="background-color: #f1c40f;">&lt;&lt; TimeAP &gt;&gt;</span>
  </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 249.344px;">Date Employer Notified</td>
            <td style="width: 696.094px;" colspan="3">
  <span id="Datenotify" class="fields"
                    style="background-color: #f1c40f;">&lt;&lt; Datenotify &gt;&gt;</span>
  </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 249.344px;">Where did the incident (or hazard) occur?</td>
            <td style="width: 696.094px;" colspan="3">
  <span id="WhereIncident" class="fields"
                    style="background-color: #f1c40f;">&lt;&lt; WhereIncident &gt;&gt;</span>
  </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 959.219px;" colspan="4">Description of the incident (or hazard) and cause</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 959.219px;" colspan="4">
  <span id="DescriptionIncident" class="fields"
                    style="background-color: #f1c40f;">&lt;&lt; DescriptionIncident &gt;&gt;</span>
  </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 249.344px;">Were there any witnesses to the incident (or hazard)?</td>
            <td style="width: 696.094px;" colspan="3">
  <span id="Witnesses" class="fields"
                    style="background-color: #f1c40f;">&lt;&lt; Witnesses &gt;&gt;</span>
  </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 249.344px;">Name</td>
            <td style="width: 349.219px;">
  <span id="Name1" class="fields" style="background-color: #f1c40f;">&lt;&lt;
                    Name1 &gt;&gt;</span>
  </td>
            <td style="width: 157.609px;">Contact telephone</td>
            <td style="width: 161.672px;">
  <span id="ContactTel1" class="fields"
                    style="background-color: #f1c40f;">&lt;&lt; ContactTel1 &gt;&gt;</span>
  </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 249.344px;">Name</td>
            <td style="width: 349.234px;">
  <span id="Name2" class="fields" style="background-color: #f1c40f;">&lt;&lt;
                    Name2 &gt;&gt;</span>
  </td>
            <td style="width: 157.594px;">Contact telephone</td>
            <td style="width: 161.703px;">
  <span id="ContactTel2" class="fields"
                    style="background-color: #f1c40f;">&lt;&lt; ContactTel2 &gt;&gt;</span>
  </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 249.344px;">Part/s of body injured</td>
            <td style="width: 696.094px;" colspan="3">
                <div id="PartofBody" class="ng-binding" draggable="true">PartofBody</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
       
        
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 249.344px;">Did you return to work after treatment?</td>
            <td style="width: 696.094px;" colspan="3">
  <span id="ReturntoWork" class="fields"
                    style="background-color: #f1c40f;">&lt;&lt; ReturntoWork &gt;&gt;</span>
  </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  `
  let finalHtml = '';
    this.getStringInBetween(htmldata, '<span', 'span>', arr);
    arr.forEach(element => {
      htmldata = htmldata.replace(element.html,this.fieldsHtml[element.name].html);
      // if (this.fieldsHtml[element.name].field.type == 'checkbox') {
      //   this.form.addControl(this.fieldsHtml[element.name].field.name, new FormGroup({}));
      //   this.fieldsHtml[element.name].field.options.forEach(o => {
      //     (this.form.get(this.fieldsHtml[element.name].field.name) as FormGroup).addControl(
      //       o.key,
      //       new FormControl(false)
      //     );
      //   });
      // } else {
      //   this.form.addControl(
      //     this.fieldsHtml[element.name].field.name,
      //     new FormControl(
      //       this.fieldsHtml[element.name].field.value || '',
      //       this.fieldsHtml[element.name].field.required ? Validators.required : null
      //     )
      //   );
      // }
    });
    this.htmlRender = htmldata;
    console.log(this.htmlRender);
   // this.htmlRender = this.sanitizer.sanitize(htmldata);
    // let b  = this.htmlData.split('<span');
    setTimeout(() => {
      arr.forEach(element => {
         
        // const control = this.fb.control(
        //     {value: this.fieldsHtml[element.name].field.value, disabled: false},[Validators.required]
        //   ); 
        //   this.form.addControl(this.fieldsHtml[element.name].field.name, control); 

          this.form.addControl(
            this.fieldsHtml[element.name].field.name,
            new FormControl(
              this.fieldsHtml[element.name].field.value || '',
              this.fieldsHtml[element.name].field.required ? Validators.required : null
            )
          );


          // this.form.addControl(
          //   this.fieldsHtml[element.name].field.name,
          //   new FormControl(
          //     this.fieldsHtml[element.name].field.value || '',Validators.required
          //   )
          // );

     // this.form.addControl(this.fieldsHtml[element.name].field.name, this.fb.control( {value: this.fieldsHtml[element.name].field.value, disabled: false},[Validators.required]));
    
     //  this.form = this.fb.group({
    //   [ this.fieldsHtml[element.name].field.name]: [this.fieldsHtml[element.name].field.value,[Validators.required]]
    // });
  });
    }, 100);
      
  }
  get isValid() { return this.form.valid; }
    get isDirty() { return this.form.dirty; }
  ngOnInit() {
    
  }
  ngAfterViewInit(){
    // this.unsubcribe = this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(update => {
    //   console.log(update);
    // });
  }
  getStringInBetween(string, start, end, arr) {
    // start and end will be excluded


    let indexOfStart = string.indexOf(start);

    let newString = string.slice(indexOfStart);
    let indexOfEnd = newString.indexOf(end);
    let spanHtml = newString.slice(0, indexOfEnd + end.length);
    let idStrIndex = spanHtml.indexOf('id=');
    let idStr = spanHtml.slice(idStrIndex + 4);
    let indexOfEndId = idStr.indexOf('"');
    let idString = idStr.slice(0, indexOfEndId);
    arr.push({ name: idString, html: spanHtml });
    string = string.replace(spanHtml, '');
    if (string.indexOf('<span') != -1) {
      this.getStringInBetween(string, '<span', 'span>', arr)
    } else {
      return arr;
    }

  }
  saveItem(){
    console.log(this.form.value);
  }
```

```html
<form id="myform" [formGroup]="form"  (submit)="saveItem()">
<div  [innerHtml]='htmlRender' ></div>
 
 <div>{{form?.value|json}}</div>
 <button type="submit" form="myform">SAVE</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please elaborate on what you see and what you expected to see and what is not working according to you. We need a [mcve] and not just a code dump - which you aught to know after 5 years at SO

Answer (score 0):

First of all that you should try to avoid using innerHTML as angular gives you tons of ways to manipulate the DOM.

**Any of the HTML with Angular specific things like binding or directives, etc. don’t work because it’s not supported by Angular 2+ when using innerHTML.**

I would suggest improving on the design of what you want to achieve:

1. Build the form on the front end and get the configs from BE and perhaps change the available options and labels.
2. Should you need dynamic fields give a try to array form. This should enable you to generate any type of form based on your backend input.

Comment: In starting i was using formcontrol, but now i m using ngModel.
now issue is "Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'".
I have already imported FormsModule, but its not working.